# What does "China’s Confidence Rises in Its Military" mean?

Tags: word-order

I'm wondering what is the meaning of the WSJ's title "China’s Confidence Rises in Its Military" (https://www.wsj.com/articles/chinas-confidence-rises-in-its-military-u-s-says-11547597775).

Is it exactly the same as "China’s Confidence in Its Military Rises" or something different?

What confuses me is that the word order in the original title seems rather unusual to me if the meaning is as I described above, and that makes me think what if I'm missing something completely and it means, for example, 'China’s Confidence Rises because of Its Military'?

Comment: The second might be misconstrued as having confidence in this thing called "Military Rises", let alone the interpretation of their *military rising* (as if in preparation for war). That is *the* perfect word order if the goal was least click bait.

Comment: @Mazura. In my dialect, the title sentence is impossible, even in headlines. The second one is fine, and cannot be misconstrued the way you say. The only thing I can think of to make any sense of this is that they wanted *within* instead of *in*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> China's confidence rises in its military.

This can be interpreted in two different ways.

---

The first interpretation is what you've provided:

> China’s confidence in its military rises.

However, it's possible to also interpret it to mean this:

> The level of confidence among China's military personnel rises.

In other words, it *could* be saying that Chinese military personnel have an increased level of confidence.

---

The second interpretation is not as likely, but there's nothing about the syntax of the sentence that rules it out.

Of course, the body of the article itself indicates that it's the first interpretation that was intended. But if you're only looking at the sentence itself, the meaning is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing I could come up with. It should have been *within*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it exactly the same as "China’s Confidence in Its Military Rises"

Yes they mean the same. There is a slight difference in emphasis. The first emphasises that China’s confidence is rising and then goes on to say why. The second allows us to wonder for a moment whether China’s confidence in its military is rising/falling or changing in some other way. As a news headline, the first is preferable because it gets the reader's attention to the important point more quickly.

Both versions are grammatical.

**Grammar**

"China’s Confidence Rises in Its Military" ('in its military' is adverbial to 'rise')

"China’s Confidence in Its Military Rises" ('in its military' is adjectival to 'confidence')

Comment: But isn't it a bit more than emphasis because in one case the subject is 'China’s confidence' (in general) and in another 'China’s confidence in its military' (but not in other things)?

Comment: @gdy - Yes, I think you are right about that, at least in terms of syntax. However in terms of semantics I can't see a difference.

Comment: May I ask you more questions to make sure I understand how it works?


Does it follow that it would be correct to say 'My confidence rises in my knowledge'?

Comment: That is a good question. I should mention that this sort of sentence is generally reserved for journalism and especially for headlines. Thus you would be very unlikely to hear it in speech. I think for that reason, 'My confidence rises in my knowledge' or 'My confidence in my knowledge rises' are both unlikely because a headline about 'me' rather than about a state or an organisation is unusual.